# browser.driver.findElement VS browser.findElement

Tags: protractor

Can we use `browser.findElement()` method for non Angular application instead of using `browser.driver.findElement()` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your question is for `browser.driver.findElement` vs `browser.element`

`browser.driver.findElement` method returns `webElement` which is the provided by `webDriver`(Selenium).
When you call `browser.driver.findElement(locator)`, WebDriver immediately sends a command over to the browser asking it to locate the element. These `WebElement` provides actions methods which can be used to interact with browser.

`browser.element` method returns `ElementFinder` object which is provided by `protractor`.
Unlike `WebElement` when you call `browser.element(locator)`, `ElementFinders` just store the locator information but won't ask browser to find element until an action method is called.
This is great for creating page objects, because we'll be able to reuse things which defined in setup (before a page may have been loaded).
All `WebElement` actions are wrapped and available on the `ElementFinder`, in addition to a couple other helper methods provided by protractor.

Also you can always access the underlying `WebElement` using `element(locator).getWebElement()`, but you should not need to as you can use `browser.element(locator)` method for non Angular application also.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to access the webdriver instance by using **browser.driver**:

```
browser.driver.findElement(by.css('[data-ptor="submit-btn"]'));
```

It can be even more elegant, in your config.js:

```
onPrepare: function() {
   global.dvr = browser.driver;
}
```

In your test:

```
dvr.findElement(by.css('[data-ptor="submit-btn"]'));
```

Protractor waits for Angular to finish its work, though you can tell it not to be that smart about your non-Angular app:

```
beforeEach(function() {
   return browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
});
```